Create object based on union type from array
I have weakly/implicit data structure as input and want to convert it into a more strict/explicit structure.
Take as simplified example a time tracking system where a numeric value of worked hours is mapped for each day of the week. So we have Monday 8 hours, Tuesday 3 hours, ….
The input type is just an Array of integers. For the internal representation I‘ve the following types:
const WEEKDAYS = [ "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" ] as const;
type Weekday = typeof WEEKDAYS[number];
type TrackedHours = Record<Weekday, number>;

The approach to use a const array to infer the type from is already a preparation for my current solution approach later.
So I want to write a function which converts from the input data of an array to this structure.
declare function parseTrackedHours(data: number[]): TrackedHours;

Taking into account scenarios with more lengthy type unions (e.g. days of a month), I would like to write a (functional?) algorithm to do the job. With plain JavaScript, a reduce comes into my mind:
function parseTrackedHours(data: number[]): TrackedHours {
  return WEEKDAYS.reduce(
    (trackedHours, weekday, index) => ({
      [weekday]: data[index] ?? 0,
      ...trackingHours,
    }),
    {},
  ); 
}

This works fine from an algorithmic point of view and I’m pretty happy with that. But it doesn’t work in terms of inferred types by the compiler. Because the initial {} is not of type TrackedHours. I could do a simple type-cast to make the compiler accept it. But casting the initial value of the reduce function makes the whole accumulator function not type-safe. So I can make any stupid mistake in the implementation (especially for more complicated cases than the one above) or change something about the outer type-system and it would be just fine during compile-time. So I would prefer to not type-cast the initial value here.
But maybe this approach is the wrong direction anyhow. Could someone show me a type-safe algorithm for the above example?

TS doesn't strongly type operations like this; the same basic issue is described at this question where it's tuple-to-tuple. You need type assertions somewhere or to write your own call signatures.  The closest I can get here is to try to strongly type Object.fromEntries() as shown in this playground link but even this is not safe because T[] isn't guaranteed to contain every value of type T. Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source. If not, what's missing?

Thanks for the fast reply! And sorry for the slow response in return.
Hmm. I'm not sure if I'm better of now. Because I end up with an object type where all values are of any. A quick attempt to improve the fromEntries signature did not work out.

"Because I end up with an object type where all values are of any". I don't see it, where is that? My tests of fromEntries look good to me. How should we proceed from here?
